# Groovy template engine escapes bracket brace in java

Tags: groovy

Recently I had to use Groovy template engine to render some strings received from  the frontend. Some strings look like `${condition_set[0].name}` And here the problem: Groovy template engine treats condition_set an array and '.' is like method invoking notation. So it cannot take the string directly like condition_set[0].name and find the bindings in the engine. Is there any way in groovy to escape '[',']' and '.'?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive an input in a format that cannot be parsed as a simple template variable, then you can switch to [`GStringTemplateEngine`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) which allows you using sections of a plain Groovy code that can easily read a map key like `'condition_set[0].name'`. Take a look at the following example:

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

def text = '''
This is <%= getVariable("condition_set[]") %>

This is <%= getVariable("condition_set[0].name") %>
'''.trim()

def binding = ['condition_set[]': 'test', 'condition_set[0].name': 'TEMPLATE']

def engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()

println engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
```

The most important change comparing to your previous example is that instead of using simple template variables now we are executing `getVariable()` method on a `Binding` object. It is important to start section with `<%=` so the result of `getVariable()` method call gets returned to the template parser. If you run this example it will produce following output:

```
This is test

This is TEMPLATE
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Szymon. Thanks for your answer. It looks useful and I will try it tomorrow. By the way, thank you for the editing of question. I will accept this answer if it works on the project.